# I'm trying to achieve this delayed look with my wordpress photo gallery - Does anyone know how to do it?

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I'm trying to achieve this look with my photo gallery. Does anyone know how I can achieve it? - I don't want to use the theme that has been here. Is there a worpress app that does this?

https://www.simplicitywebdesign.co.nz/portfolio/

Thanks

Have checked and downloaded popular options but can't seem to recreate it.

Comment: If you are open to using JS and a JS library, [GSAP staggers](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Staggers) provides the ability to make that effect